# QCalendarWidget Renders Small

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to use the `QCalendarWidget` but it doesn't render in the user interface as expected.  The examples that I have seen show a calendar picker like object, but in my case I get a quite small rendering of a field.  Here's what it looks like in the UI:

[image: QCalendarWidget]

This is my first time using it so I am not sure if I am missing a step.  Any thoughts on what I could be doing incorrectly?  Here is the complete code being used:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QCalendarWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


import sys

class Example(QMainWindow):

   def __init__(self):
      super(Example, self).__init__()

      self.initUI()

   def initUI(self):

      cal = QCalendarWidget(self)
      cal.setGridVisible(True)
      cal.move(20, 20)
      cal.clicked[QtCore.QDate].connect(self.showDate)

      self.lbl = QLabel(self)
      date = cal.selectedDate()
      self.lbl.setText(date.toString())
      self.lbl.move(20, 200)

      self.setGeometry(100,100,300,300)
      self.setWindowTitle('Calendar')
      self.show()

   def showDate(self, date):

      self.lbl.setText(date.toString())

def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = Example()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a layout, for example a QVBoxLayout, in the centralWidget of QMainWindow:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        cal = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(gridVisible=True)
        cal.clicked.connect(self.showDate)

        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        date = cal.selectedDate()
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString())

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(cal)
        lay.addWidget(self.lbl)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Calendar")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QDate)
    def showDate(self, date):
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString())


def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = Example()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome!  Thank you!